# Why my visual c++ is not triggering stack corruption error in situation of stack corruption

Tags: c++

I have following code..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct data

{
    int d;
};
void main()
{
    data *p=(data*)malloc(sizeof(data));
    p->d=10;
    free(p);
    p->d=10;

    _getch();
}
```

I expect a stack corruption error while running the code but Visual studio fires nothing...even after freeing p...

It must trigger error of accssesing unreferenced pointer...But still it continues reading and writing...Why this is happening also I have this following code..

```
int a[]={1,2,3};
void main()
{
    a[5]=100;

    _getch();
}
```

here I am accssesing array out of bound, but still it continues..
It never happned before.I cant say whats wrong here?

Comment: Why "stack curruption"? Do you mean "heap corruption"? But anyway the answer below applies.

Comment: Yeah...both actually .sorry

Answer (score 6):

1. The behaviour of the second `p->d=10;` is *undefined*. Not crashing is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour. (You may well find that `free` doesn't actually give the memory back to the operating system in your particular case.)
2. `a[5]=100;` is undefined too. Again, you might find that the C++ runtime library / operating system have allocated memory in excess of 3 `int`s.
3. Notwithstanding (1) and (2), your program is undefined as you need to use `int main()`. Again, permitting compilation and runtime behaviour consistent with that you'd get with `int main()` is a manifestation of undefined behaviour.

Comment: If I used a c compiler it won't crash then?

Comment: These things sometimes happen and sometimes don't... why so>

Comment: @ShivanshuRaj: That's the nature of undefined behaviour. If you knew what was going to happen, and when, then it wouldn't be undefined, innit?!

Answer (score 1):

Terminology: STACK and HEAP are not the same thing.

Stack is used for static memory allocation: char foo[100];

Heap is used for dynamic memory allocation: char * foo = malloc(100);

It has been a few years since I used visual C++. I seem to recall it has compile and maybe link time options to check for memory issues.

At runtime, the C/C++ runtime system asks for memory from the operating system, it gets the memory in large blocks, then the C/C++ runtime code slices it up as needed. When you step outside of that block, you may get run time errors. You may randomly get other errors.

When function2() correctly uses that part of the block of memory that function1() has corrupted, then you may get weird run time errors as you have corrupted the stack or heap. When no other part of your program uses that same memory you have corrupted, then it is likely you will not see any error. You code still has that bug, however it does not show up until another part of your code or the C/C++ runtime noticed you stepped on its variables.

Comment: This hidden bug is dangerous..How should I tackle this..?

Comment: by calling the free(p) I deallocated the pointer and didn't assigned NULL pointer to it..and accsessed the pointer...By doing so I am using the corrupted memory again..then why dont it crash..?

Comment: It means if I use the variable by other function in here ...This would more likely  to crash....na